# Fail to continue parsing after correct input

Tags: yacc, lex

I have two input numbers separated by ','.
The program works fine for the first try, but for the second try it always ends with error.
How do I keep parsing?

lex file snippet:

```
 #include "y.tab.h"
%%
[0-9]+ { yylval = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER; }

. return yytext[0];
%%
```

yacc file snippet:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
int yylex();
int yyerror();
%}
%start s
%token NUMBER
%%
s: NUMBER ',' NUMBER{
            if(($1 % 3 == 0) && ($3 % 2 == 0)) {printf("OK");}
            else{printf("NOT OK, try again.");}
            };
%%
int main(){ return yyparse(); }

int yyerror() { printf("Error Occured.\n"); return 0; }
```

output snippet:

```
benjamin@benjamin-VirtualBox:~$ ./ex1 
15,4
OK
15,4
Error Occured.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your start rule (indeed, your only rule) is:

```
s: NUMBER ',' NUMBER
```

That means that an input consists of a `NUMBER`, a `','` and another `NUMBER`.

That's it. After the parser encounters those three things, it expects an end of input indicator, because that's what you've told it a complete input looks like.

If you want to accept multiple lines, each consisting of two numbers separated by a comma, you'll need to write a grammar which describes that input. (And in order to describe the fact that they are lines, you'll probably want to make a newline character a token. Right now, it falls through the the scanner's default rule, because in (f)lex `.` doesn't match a newline character.) You'll also probably want to include an `error` production so that your parser doesn't suddenly terminate on the first error.

Alternatively, you could parse your input one line at a time by reading the lines yourself, perhaps using `fgets` or the [Posix-standard `getline` function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), and then passing each line to your scanner using [`yy_scan_string`](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html#index-yy_005fscan_005fstring)

Comment: appreciate the detailed explenation! can you guide me with code sample of a grammer that keep getting correct input? I've tried but it wasn't going so well.

Comment: @benjamin: what did you try?

Comment: @benjamin: You might take a look at this similar question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49260447/1566221

Comment: I tried to write a grammer that describe the input the way that it keep run until error but I didn't succeed doing it. anyway, I'll check the similar question and try again. thx :)